# Common Lisp structures with dynamically scoped slots

Tags: structure, common-lisp, dynamic-scope

Common Lisp is lexically scoped, but there is a possibility to create dynamic bindings with `(declare (special *var*))`. What I need, is a way to create a dynamically scoped structure slot, whose value is visible to all other slots. Here is an example:

```
(defun start-thread ()
  *delay*) ;; We defer the binding of *delay*
```

This works for a usual lexical environment:

```
(let ((*delay* 1))
  (declare (special *delay*))
  (start-thread)) ;; returns 1
```

This does not work:

```
(defstruct table  
  (*delay* 0)
  (thread (start-thread)))

(make-table) ;; => Error: *delay* is unbound.
```

My questions are

1. How to refer to the slot *delay* from other slots?
2. How to make the slot *delay* dynamically scoped, so that its value becomes visible
   for the function `(start-thread)` ?

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to realise that there's no good way to have a dynamically-scoped slot in an object (unless the implementation has some deep magic to support this): the only approach that will work is to use, essentially, explicit shallow-binding.  Something like this macro, for instance (this has no error checking at all: I just typed it in):

```
(defmacro with-horrible-shallow-bound-slots ((&rest slotds) object &body forms)
  (let ((ovar (make-symbol "OBJECT"))
        (slot-vars (mapcar (lambda (slotd)
                             (make-symbol (symbol-name (first slotd))))
                           slotds)))
    `(let ((,ovar ,object))
       (let ,(mapcar (lambda (v slotd)
                       `(,v (,(first slotd) ,ovar)))
                     slot-vars slotds)
         (unwind-protect
             (progn
               (setf ,@(mapcan (lambda (slotd)
                                 `((,(first slotd) ,ovar) ,(second slotd)))
                               slotds))
               ,@forms)
           (setf ,@(mapcan (lambda (slotd slot-var)
                                 `((,(first slotd) ,ovar) ,slot-var))
                           slotds slot-vars)))))))
```

And now if we have some structure:

```
(defstruct foo
  (x 0))
```

Then

```
(with-horrible-shallow-bound-slots ((foo-x 1)) foo
  (print (foo-x foo)))
```

expands to

```
(let ((#:object foo))
  (let ((#:foo-x (foo-x #:object)))
    (unwind-protect
        (progn (setf (foo-x #:object) 1) (print (foo-x foo)))
      (setf (foo-x #:object) #:foo-x))))
```

where all the gensyms with the same name are in fact the same.  And so:

```
> (let ((foo (make-foo)))
    (with-horrible-shallow-bound-slots ((foo-x 1)) foo
      (print (foo-x foo)))
    (print (foo-x foo))
    (values))
1
0
```

But this is a terrible approach because shallow binding is terrible in the presence of multiple threads: any other thread that wants to look at `foo`'s slots will *also* see the temporary value.  So this is just horrid.

A good approach is then to realise that while you can't safely dynamically-bind a slot in an object, you *can* dynamically bind a value which that slot indexes by using a secret special variable to hold a  stack of bindings.  In this approach the values of slots do not change, but the values they *index* do, and can do so safely in the presence of multiple threads.

A way of doing this this is [Tim Bradshaw's `fluids`](https://tfeb.github.io/tfeb-lisp-toys/#dynamic-bindings-for-fields-fluids) toy.  The way this works is that you define the value of a slot to be a fluid, and then you can bind that fluid's value, which binding has dynamic scope.

```
(defstruct foo
  (slot (make-fluid)))

(defun outer (v)
  (let ((it (make-foo)))
    (setf (fluid-value (foo-slot it) t) v) ;set global value
    (values (fluid-let (((foo-slot it) (1+ (fluid-value (foo-slot it)))))
              (inner it))
            (fluid-value (foo-slot it)))))

(defun inner (thing)
  (fluid-value (foo-slot thing)))
```

This often works better with CLOS objects because of the additional flexibility in things like naming and what you expose (you almost never want to be able to assign to a slot whose value is a fluid, for instance: you want to assign the value of the fluid).

The system uses a special variable behind the scenes to implement deep binding for fluids, so will work properly with threads (ie distinct threads can have different bindings for a fluid) assuming the implementation treats special variables sensibly (which I'm sure all multithreaded implementations do).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this makes sense.  Variables have scope and extent, but values just *are*, and slots are just parts of values.  Additionally, threads do not inherit dynamic bindings.

If you want to have some kind of object that is *dynamically* changed (so to speak), you need to put it into a dynamic variable as a whole value, and do re-bindings with modified versions (preferably on the basis of some immutability, i. e. *persistent datastructures*, e. g. with FSet).

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing a bit of guessing about what you need here, but I think using a class and initialize-instance will give you what you want. In the code below, I rewrote your struct as a class, and the object itself is passed to initialize-instance in a call to (make-instance 'table).

```lisp
(defclass table ()
  ((delay :initform 5)
   (thread)))

(defun start-my-thread (obj)
  (print (slot-value obj 'delay)))

(defmethod initialize-instance :after ((obj table) &key)
  (start-my-thread obj))

(make-instance 'table)
; above call will print 5
```